# Problem at bridging vertices

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm new to Blender, and I'm learning how to model characters. The thing is that I want to fill the gap between these edges, but this happens when I try to bridge these vertices:

[image]

It selects some vertices and edges that I didn't select. Do you know why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like there are double vertices in your mesh. In Edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to open the vertex special menu, and click on Remove Doubles.

It also seems like you selected a loop around the eye by choosing one vertex, and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while choosing a second. When you do this, every vertex along the shortest route between the two is also selected. I'm guessing you wanted to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> but missed. It is super easy to hit something in Blender and have very unexpected and confusing results, when you are learning.